# simulation using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, simulation

[image: l]

can anybody tell me what is the meaning of simulator granularity in this question. Furthermore, how I can define the number of delta-cycles

Comment: Each simulator has a minimum time resolution. So values beneath 10 ns are rounded or trunkated to zero. VHDL defines 1 fs as smallest possible time resolution but most simulators use 1 ps or 1 ns as minimum time resolution. If needed it can be changed to 1 fs.

Comment: 'granularity' does not appear in the standard, provide context. @Paebbels, per IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.4.2 Predefined physical types, para 2 "... It is an error if a given unit of type TIME appears anywhere within the design hierarchy defining a model to be elaborated, and if the position number of that unit is less than that of the secondary unit selected as the resolution limit for type TIME during the elaboration of the model, unless that unit is part of a physical literal whose abstract literal is either the integer value zero or the floating-point value zero." `1 ns` would be an error.

Comment: Also note in para 2 that '10 ns' is not a secondary unit  "An implementation may allow a given elaboration of a model (see Clause 14) to select a secondary unit of type TIME as the resolution limit." Also see 16.3 Package STANDARD, the declaration for type TIME, the available secondary units for a resolution limit are `fs`, `ps`, `ns`, `us`, `ms`, `sec`, `min`, and `hr`.  This question appears to be an academic invention, not a VHDL one.